# Styling Text In Div

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out how to get the text `No Managers in Database` vertically positioned in the containing `div` like the `input` elements are.

I tried adding `padding` and `margin`, but they didn't work. Any thoughts on how this could be accomplished?

http://jsfiddle.net/SKTRn/

Comment: Posting a JSFiddle with an entire metric ton of mess in the HTML pane doesn't help at all. Post a _minimal_ example, and separate the HTML and CSS out so it's easier to fiddle with.

Comment: @CodyGray, the OP simply wants `No Managers in Database` text to line up with the inputs in the `Biography` section.

Comment: Vertically? If so, what browser are you using?

Comment: @bfr Sorry, no, just horizontally. I apparently have blinders on that cause me to only see in one dimension. Approved your edits, great job fixing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CSS

```
#none {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 7px 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
```

Basically, you just have to add `display: block;` to your CSS. I just took the liberty of changing the other styles to line things up a little better (and get the font the same size as the inputs).